# Conditional background color on a n row

Tags: reactjs, react-native

so I have this table where I would like to only background color the 4th row. I tried many things however I am unable to color a single individual row.

here is my style

```
 tableRow: {
    borderTopColor: Colors.dividerColor,
    borderTopWidth: 1,
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    padding: Spacing.globalPaddingSmall,
    // backgroundColor: "red" I want only to color the 4th row
  },
```

and here is my table

```
  <View style={tableStyles.tableRow}>
    <Text style={tableStyles.tableTextFirst}>{sensor}</Text>
                        <Text style={tableStyles.tableText}>{daily}</Text>
                        <Text style={tableStyles.tableText}>{weekley}</Text>
                        <Text style={tableStyles.tableText}>{monthley}</Text>
    <Text style={tableStyles.tableText}>{average}</Text> //only color this one
  </View>
```

Comment: try adding ```<Text style={[tableStyles.tableText, {backgroundColor: 'your color'}]}>{average}</Text>```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add:

```
redRow: {
  backgroundColor: "red"
}
```

to your styles and then use it like this
`<Text style={[tableStyles.redRow, tableStyles.tableText]}>{average}</Text>`

see example: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/style

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for, the problem now is that it's red but there is a white padding. I guess there is no why to color padding?